# npm install -g react-native-cli does not work: EACCES: permission denied

Tags: macos, terminal, permission, javascript

I'm trying install `react-native-cli` in My MacBook. Executing this command in my terminal

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Getting this error

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kishore/.npm/_logs/2020-01-16T01_34_30_715Z-debug.log
```

in my `which node`

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

My `npm get prefix`

```
/usr/local
```

Help me out fix the issues.

Comment: What are the permissions of `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`?

Comment: Pemission  ```drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  128 Jan 16 12:46 node_modules```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution after many tries

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin
```

After that running working fine without any issues.

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `sudo npm install -g react-native-cli`?

Comment: What does this do and how does it adress a permission issue?

Comment: if I tried this sudo also getting this error  ```gyp ERR! configure error ```,    ```gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/fsevents/build' ```